# Local and heroku db get out of sync while migrating using alembic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, migration, flask, alembic

I'm bulding an app with Flask and Angular hosted on heroku. I have a problem with migrating heroku postgresql. I'm using [flask-migrate](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-migrate/) which is a tiny wrapper around alembic. Locally everything is fine. I got an exception when I run `heroku run upgrade` which runs alembic upgrade command.

```
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade None -> 19aeffe4063d, empty message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    manager.run()
...

   cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) relation "users" already exists
 '\nCREATE TABLE users (\n\tid SERIAL NOT NULL, \n\tusername VARCHAR(32), \n\tpassword_hash VARCHAR(128), \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id)\n)\n\n' {}
```

Simply, alembic is trying to run from the first migration which creates the db. I tried to set explicitly the proper revision with `heroku run python manage.py db upgrade +2` or revision number but the exception is the same.

```
lukas$ heroku run python manage.py db current
Running `python manage.py db current` attached to terminal... up, run.1401
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Current revision for postgres://...: None
```

My guess was that due to ephemeral filesystem of Heroku revision in not stored, but that shouldn't be a problem if I explicitly set the revision, right? :)

**How can I set the current head of revision?**

Here is relevant code:

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn server:app
init: python manage.py db init
upgrade: python manage.py db upgrade
```

models.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

ROLE_USER = 0
ROLE_ADMIN = 1


class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = "users"
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(32), unique = True, index = True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique = True)
  password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
  role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default = ROLE_USER)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the actual problem, but when you go to heroku you do not need to use `init`, as that is the command the creates a new repository. All you need to do there is the upgrade command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `init` command that you put in the `Procfile` creates a brand new Alembic repository, which is something you only do once on your development machine. When you deploy to a new machine all you need to do is run the `upgrade` command to get the database created and updated to the last revision.

Alembic and Flask-Migrate have a command called `stamp` that can help you fix this problem. With `stamp` you can tell Alembic to write the revision of your choice to the database, without touching the database itself.

For example, creating a database from scratch when there are a lot of migrations can take a long time if Alembic has to go through all the migrations one by one. Instead, you can create the database with `db.create_all()` and then run:

```
$ ./manage.py db stamp HEAD
```

and with this the database is marked as updated.

Also, at some point I favored the idea of putting maintenance commands in the `Procfile`, but these days I only put services there, so I would only leave the `web` line there. To upgrade the database I think it is more predictable to run the command explicitly:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py db upgrade
```

Comment: Many thanks stamp helped. Do you know where the current head is stored?

Comment: Yes, Alembic adds a little table to your database where it writes its state.